# How to make an auto submit with combobox in HTML5 and return the data to html file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, combobox

My code:

```
<strong>Station Name</strong>

<!--This part combobox with HTML5 -->
<input type=text list=Stations>
<datalist id=Stations>
    <option>Station1</option>
    <option>Station2</option>
    <option>Station3</option>
    <option>Station4</option>
</datalist>

<div>
    <strong>Number of Passanger</strong>
</div>
```

I want to auto submit when a station is selected and return some data (the data can be a random number) to the `Number of Passengers`. How can I do that with javascript? Is PHP needed?

Thank you any help will be appreciated.

Comment: using jquery, the specific .ajax function

Answer (score 1):

```
<datalist onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

This will automatically send the form

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden submit type button(i.e. display:none;), after page load through jquery click on it automatically(i.e. $('#submit').click() ), Create a function for clicking on submit button, call it after page loads...

EDIT:
HTML:

```
<form ...>
...
<input type="submit" id="submit" style="display:none;" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function submit_click(){
 $("#submit").click();
}
```

Now, when your auto form populating data's function called, call this function in last line `submit_click();`